# setInterval and clearInterval inside of a button

Tags: javascript

setInterval is working, the audio starts and doesn't stop.
clearInterval does not - the audio continues, forever. I've tried a few different ways, to no avail. Advice, please?

Thanks!

```
<audio id="soundEffect" src="Whoosh.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="setInterval(function(){playAudio()}, 1000)">Start Audio</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(function(){playAudio()}">Stop Audio</button>




<script type="text/javascript">

        function playAudio() {
            document.getElementById("soundEffect").play();

        }

</script>
```

Comment: You use wrong syntax. `clearInterval` expects parameter to be number returned by `setInterval`

Comment: [**READ THIS**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). Summary: To be able to use the clearInterval() method, you must use a global variable when creating the interval method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can stop an interval with an id.

Try this:

```
<audio id="soundEffect" src="Whoosh.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="startLoop()">Start Audio</button>
<button onclick="stopLoop()">Stop Audio</button>




<script type="text/javascript">

        var intervalId;

        function startLoop() {
             intervalId = setInterval(playAudio, 1000);
        }

        function stopLoop() {
             clearInterval(intervalId);
        }

        function playAudio() {
            document.getElementById("soundEffect").play();

        }

</script>
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple of seconds!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<audio id="soundEffect" src="Whoosh.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="startInterval()">Start Audio</button>
<button onclick="stopInterval()">Stop Audio</button>




<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval = '';
    function startInterval(){
        interval = setInterval(function(){playAudio()}, 1000);
    }

    function stopInterval(){
        clearInerval(interval);
    }

    function playAudio() {
        document.getElementById("soundEffect").play();
    }
</script>
```